# Concatenate a string for Flurry event iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use to use `[Flurry logEvent:@"NameOfTheEvent"];`
to crete flurry events. Now, I want to create the event but using a string.
I Have a picker view that goes from 1 to 10 and every time that somebody use it, the picker send the selected text to a string (pickervalue).

Something like: `[Flurry logEvent:@"PickerResult " + pickervalue];`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `pickervalue` is a string, you would want:

```
[Flurry logEvent:[@"PickerResult " stringByAppendingString:pickervalue]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not make more sense to use the API that accepts parameters and then the web interface can group the events more intelligently

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"PickerResult" 
  withParameters:@{ @"value" : pickerValue }];
```